# Problem with installing apk android studio

Tags: android-studio

I don't see **Installing APKs process** when I run the **AVD but it's work fine** and the virtual device runs but **I don't see my application**

Comment: does it work if you install it manually? Maye your code did not compile properly and AS did not install it on AVD.

Comment: how can I install it manually

Comment: just copy the apk to the phone and then open the apk via any file manager.